# Groups: cyclic and order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x$ be an element in group $G$ and $|x|=40$. What are the possible orders of elements in $\langle x \rangle$?

List all the elements of order $10$ in $\langle x \rangle$.

I know that $U(10)=\lbrace 1,3,7,9 \rbrace$ and $\langle 40/10 \rangle=4$ but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you explain its source, include any work you have done on the problem, and indicate where you are stuck so that we can write a response that is appropriate for your skill level.

Comment: Check this tutorial of [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The order of the elements in $\langle x\rangle$ must divide $40$. See [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)).

**Edit:**

You have that $x^{40} = e$, any element in $\langle x\rangle$ has the form $x^{m}$, where $0 \leq m < 40$. Now you want $n$ such that $(x^{m})^n = e = x^{40}$ and $m \in \mathbb Z$.

What can you take from this?

Comment: We haven't covered LaGrange's theorem. Any other way to explain?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome! If it was helpful in any way consider accepting the answer.